# Mailer uses same controller code as ___ controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

So I want to mail out a report that has class variables regularly defined by the controller. However in the mailer I have to define them again? Is there a way to not repeat this? I've thought about moving it more to the model but in the end it's still the same amount of definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to define them again, you can pass them from the controller as parameters to the mailer method.

Assuming you need @ivar1, @ivar2 and @ivar3 in your mail all you have to do is run this from the controller:

```
MyMailer.some_email(@ivar1, @ivar2, @ivar3).deliver
```

EDIT:

Having a second look at your question (and my answer), I think I may have misunderstood it in first place.

In my solution you will still have to re-define the instance variables. The values are correctly passed but you will still have to:

```
def some_email(v1, v2, v3)
  @ivar1 = v1
  @ivar2 = v2
  @ivar3 = v3
end
```

There is no way to use the **same** instance variable defined in the controller.

Comment: alright, thanks for this answer though. I may do this with a hash since there's a lot of variables.